# How to move contents before go to checkout button on checkout cart page

Tags: magento2, cart

I am using the below code to show custom data.

> file: checkout_cart_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.totals">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="block-totals" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="basetotal" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Ishaq_CheckoutBaseTotal/js/view/checkout/cart/totals/basetotal</item>
                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">20</item>
                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Ishaq_CheckoutBaseTotal/checkout/cart/totals/basetotal</item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>

                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

This is working properly but showing content after Subtotal.

I have used move tag as below but it has no effect.

`<move element="checkout.cart.totals" destination="checkout.cart.methods" before="-" />`

[image]

How to show contents before **Proceed/Go to Checkout Button**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Changing the XML file and using my KnocoutJS inside phtml now it is working.

> app/code/Ishaq/CheckoutBaseTotal/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="checkout.cart.totals.container">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" 
                name="checkout.cart.basetotal.block" 
                after="checkout.cart.totals" 
                template="Ishaq_CheckoutBaseTotal::basetotal.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
        
    </body>
</page>
```

> app/code/Ishaq/CheckoutBaseTotal/view/frontend/templates/basetotal.phtml

```
<div id="basetotal-component" data-bind="scope:'basetotalcomponent'">
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#basetotal-component": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
               "components": {
                    "basetotalcomponent": {
                        "component": "Ishaq_CheckoutBaseTotal/js/view/checkout/cart/totals/basetotal"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add your code in that template too

```
/app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Checkout/templates/onepage/link.phtml
```

or you can move via xml

```
<move element="your_element_name" destination="checkout.cart.methods" before="-" />
```

Comment: I am using move tag as suggested but still position of the content is same. see my updated question

Comment: try to change name in your xml    ``<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.totals">``
 to        ``<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.methods">``